# How can i send a POST request from Java which is in for loop

Tags: java, json, multithreading, rest, parallel-processing

I have a loop which sends out a POST request to a URL.
for every client ID in the list i have to make a request.
But this is done sequentially.
Whats the best way to get the request parallel and faster.

I have option to send out request as JSON in array, but it gives me undesirable output.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < Clients.clients.size(); i++){
         String itemIdHistory = URLResponseGetPost.postRequest(Resources.COMPANY_ZABBIX_URL, itemIdJsonResponse);
    }
```

Comment: 1. The question has nothing to do with JSON in particular (unless you provide how JSON makes a difference here)  2. I cannot see how your request is different based on different client.  3. `URLResponseGetPost` does not seems something standard.  Clueless on what it does internally.  The easiest way based on what you provided is to `parallelStream`, something like `clients.parallelStream().map(c -> URLResponseGetPost.postRequest(blablabla)).collect(whateverCollectorSuitable);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at the `ExecutorService`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Here is an example:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Set<Callable<String>> callables = new HashSet<Callable<String>>();
callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "Task 1";
    }
});
callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "Task 2";
    }
});
callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "Task 3";
    }
});

List<Future<String>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(callables);
for(Future<String> future : futures){
    System.out.println("future.get = " + future.get());
}
executorService.shutdown();
```

To run in parallel, consider using a thread pool with more threads: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-